# If a formula has a Morley Rank then it is less then $|T|^+$

Tags: model-theory

We saw in class that given a complete theory $T$, then if $MR\varphi\ge (2^{|T|})^+$ then $MR\varphi=\infty$ And we ware told that Lachlan improved this result to $|T|^+$.

To prove it, I assume towards contradiction that we have $\infty>MR\varphi\ge|T|^+$ and then to construct a binary tree, starting with $\varphi$, and from that we conclude that $MR\varphi=\infty$. But I don't see the right way to build the tree... help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A theorem that is definitely under represented in the literature. Anyway here is as extract from by notes, its terse, but the basic idea is there:

Definition:
 $\alpha_T$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ with the property that if
$\alpha \leq \mbox{MR}(\varphi)$ then $\mbox{MR}(\varphi)= \infty$.

Theorem [Lachlan]
If $\mathcal{L}$  is countable, then
$$\alpha_T \leq \omega_1$$

Proof:
Let $\psi$ be a formula such that $\omega_1 \leq \mbox{MR}(\psi)$.
Then for every $\alpha < \omega_1$,  $\alpha +1 \leq \mbox{MR}(\psi)$.
Thus there are $\varphi_{\alpha}(\overline{x},\overline{b}_{\alpha})$ such
that  $$\alpha \leq \mbox{MR}(\psi(\overline{x}) \wedge
\varphi_{\alpha}(\overline{x},\overline{b}_{\alpha}) ) $$ and
 $$\alpha \leq \mbox{MR}(\psi(\overline{x}) \wedge
\neg \varphi_{\alpha}(\overline{x},\overline{b}_{\alpha}) ). $$
Since there are at most $\aleph_0$ many formulas there must be one formula that
occurs uncountably often. Call this formula
$\varphi_{\emptyset}(\overline{x},\overline{y})$.
Thus for every $\alpha < \omega_1$ there is $\overline{b}$ such that

$$\alpha +1\leq \mbox{MR}(\psi(\overline{x}) \wedge
\varphi_{\emptyset}(\overline{x},\overline{b}) ) $$ and
 $$\alpha +1 \leq \mbox{MR}(\psi(\overline{x}) \wedge
\neg \varphi_{\emptyset}(\overline{x},\overline{b}) ). $$
By a repetition of the same argument we have
$\varphi_{s}(\overline{x},\overline{y}_s)$  for $s \in 2^{<\omega}$
such that all paths through the tree are consistent.
Thus by compactness there is an infinite tree and $ \mbox{MR}(\psi) =\infty$.

Comment: By repetition of the same argument you mean to repeat the same process for $\varphi _{\emptyset}$? I understand how you got $\varphi _{\emptyset}$ But not the following steps, on how you get the tree. could you explain?

Comment: One starts with $\psi$ and then the argument shows how to split this into two disjoint formulas using $\varphi$ and $\neg \varphi$ each of these two formulas can then be split by the same argument etc. So you have build a tree of formulas, and finite part of which can be provided with parameters p to make it consistent.

Comment: I see, so won't we need a parameter $\bar{b}$ s.t $MR\varphi _{\emptyset} (\bar{x} ,\bar{b} )\ge\omega _1$? in order for us to split it again. (also for it's negation)

Comment: No you dont get one parameter, just a parameter for each ordinal, but this is not a problem, they key thing is the formula is fixed.

Comment: But then we cannot repeat the same process for $\varphi _{\emptyset}$. Maybe we get that $MR\varphi _{\emptyset} (\bar{x},\bar{y})\ge\omega _1$ so we can repeat the process for that? (without parameters) and then deal with the parameters.

Comment: For the purpose of induction change you assumption to $\forall \alpha\exists b  (\alpha+1\leq MR(\psi(x,b)))$ then the above argument is just the same with minor notation changes.